# how to add prefix in auto generated field value in database table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

we have a auto-generated field in database table and we want to add prefix in auto-generated value Like AVL0001.

Answer (score 0):

So you could do it a couple ways... Is this an auto-index field in the database? If it is an integer type, then you won't be able to include data like you are mentioning above, however, if it is something generated from a script, just concatenate the number and your prefix before insert. You could probably also do this with a trigger on the database. Any additional details would help improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentdbvalue = 'example';
$prefix = 'AVL0001';

$newvalue = $prefix.$currentdbvalue;
```

outputs "AVL0001example"

or if you'd like an underscore u can use:

```
$newvalue = $prefix."_".$currentdbvalue;
```

which would output "AVL0001_example"

Answer (score 0):

Let `id` be your table column. You can add `AVL` ahead of your `id` by concatenating both in your sql query.

ie In `Mysql`,

```
$yourid="1";

INSERT INTO table( id ) 
VALUES (
CONCAT( "AVL", $yourid, id  )
)
```

Or you can concatenate the AVL with `yourid` before inserting it into database like,

```
$yourid="AVL"."1";
```

**In either way you cannot add it into an auto incrementing field. Because its type is `INT`.**